# Deployed Azure SignalR Function Failed: The SignalR Service connection string or endpoints are not set

Tags: signalr, azure-signalr

**I receive the following error for the code below:**

```
_hub = new HubConnectionBuilder()
    .WithUrl("https://MY_AZURE_FUNCTION.azurewebsites.net/api")
    .Build();

await _hub.StartAsync(); // ERROR OCCURRS HERE
```

> 'Response status code does not indicate success: 500 (Internal Server
> Error).'

**Log Stream provided the following details:**

> 2021-07-08T16:17:04.786 [Error] Executed 'negotiate' (Failed,
> Id=dcca623f-f851-4352-a35d-a12567d2f8bb,
> Duration=26ms)System.InvalidOperationException : The SignalR Service
> connection string or endpoints are not set.at
> Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Extensions.SignalRService.ServiceManagerStore.<>c.

**My Configuration is the following:**

[image]

**Where else would I set the SignalR connection string?**

Answer (score -1):

You might have put the connection string setting in the client project, while it should be in the hub project https://MY_AZURE_FUNCTION.azurewebsites.net/api

Comment: I'm don't understand. Can you elaborate?

Comment: _hub = new HubConnectionBuilder() ... is your client code which seems to be an azure app service. your Hub is in the azure function MY_AZURE_FUNCTION.azurewebsites.net/api and the conntectionstring to signalr service should be set here: func settings add AzureSignalRConnectionString '<signalr-connection-string>'  Please following this link:https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-signalr/signalr-quickstart-azure-functions-csharp