# Azure functions - SignalR output binding failure: ServiceEndpoints is empty. ConnectionString is null, empty, or consists only of white-space

Tags: azure-functions, azure-signalr, dotnet-isolated

I'm trying to run an Azure function using SignalR output binding in dotnet-isolated process, but I always have this error

"Executed 'Functions.SendToGroup' (Failed,..)
System.Private.CoreLib: Exception while executing function: Functions.SendToGroup. Microsoft.Azure.SignalR.Management: ServiceEndpoints is empty. ConnectionString is  null, empty, or consists only of white-space."

either running it locally or remotely.

The connection string is defined in the local.settings,json file using the key

```
"AzureSignalRConnectionString": ""
```

This is the code of the input and output Azure functions (taken from the example here https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-bindings-signalr-service-output?tabs=isolated-process&pivots=programming-language-csharp)

```
        [Function("negotiate")]
        public static string Negotiate(
            [HttpTrigger(AuthorizationLevel.Anonymous)] HttpRequestData req,
            [SignalRConnectionInfoInput(HubName = "dttelemetry")] string connectionInfo)
        {
            // The serialization of the connection info object is done by the framework. It should be camel case. The SignalR client respects the camel case response only.
            return connectionInfo;
        }
```

```
    [Function("SendToGroup")]
    [SignalROutput(HubName = "dttelemetry", ConnectionStringSetting = "SignalRConnection")]
    public static SignalRMessageAction SendToGroup([HttpTrigger(AuthorizationLevel.Anonymous, "post")] HttpRequestData req)
    {
        using var bodyReader = new StreamReader(req.Body);
        SignalRMessageAction messageAction =  new SignalRMessageAction("newMessage")
        {
            Arguments = new[] { bodyReader.ReadToEnd() },
            GroupName = "groupToSend"
        };
        return messageAction;
    }
```

local.settings.json

```
{
"IsEncrypted": false,
"Values": {
"FUNCTIONS_WORKER_RUNTIME": "dotnet-isolated",
"AzureWebJobsStorage": "\<My AzureWebJobsStorage\> ",
"AzureSignalRConnectionString": "\<My SignalR Connection string\>"
}
}
```

[Function App Configuration](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EAzGC.png)

I checked this previous StackOverflow question [Deployed Azure SignalR Function Failed: The SignalR Service connection string or endpoints are not set](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68305647/deployed-azure-signalr-function-failed-the-signalr-service-connection-string-or), but it didn't answer my problem

Answer (score 0):

Here is the fix for this problem https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/1331784/azure-functions-signalr-output-binding-failure-ser

> While AzureSignalRConnectionString is the default name for the app
> setting that contains the connection string for the SignalR binding,
> since you are setting the ConnectionStringSetting argument in the
> attribute, you need to use that value instead.
>
> So, the name/key of the app setting, both when running on Azure or via
> local.settings.json, use SignalRConnection instead of
> AzureSignalRConnectionString.

I changed the definition of SignalROutput:
[Function("SendToGroup")]
[SignalROutput(HubName = "dttelemetry", **ConnectionStringSetting = "AzureSignalRConnectionString")**]